# How to test function with nonexist callback class as parameter

Tags: php, callback, phpunit

I have following problem. I doing API for our web and customer must use his function as callback in my function.

Example:

```
UserClass { 
    userMethod() {
        return $data;
    }
}

MyClass {
    myFunction (callback ) {
        doingSomething();
        doingSomething();
        $data = call_user_function($callback);
        return doingSomethingWithData($data);
    }
}
```

Problem is, that this is API and I cant implement customer class as callback, because non exist, but i need test that function will be work with expected data. Is there any possibilites how test my function using phpunit?

Thanks a lot

Comment: In example you pass `UserClass::userMethod()` as a callback to `MyClass::MyFunction`? Which of those to you want to test?

Comment: I need test myFunction(), that return right data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just pass in anonymous function that returns expected result the one you can predict output for. Make sure that it handles garbage data out/edge cases properly.
Your test can look something like that:

```
class MyClassTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    /**
     * @dataProvider myFunctionProvider
     */
    public function testMyFunction($callback, $expected)
    {
        $this->assertEquals(
            // Just as example you can create instance of class and call it.
            MyClass::MyFunction($callback),
            $expected
        );
    }

    public function myFunctionProvider()
    {
        return [
            [ function () { return 'a';}, 'a'],
            [ function () { return 'c';}, 'c'],
            [ function () { return 'b';}, 'b']
        ];
    }
}
```

As a side note change your code to:

```
function MyFunc(callable $callback) {

}
```

That'll make sure you get only callable in to your function.